# What is the best practice for show conditional confirmation message then continue?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I runned business logic when user submit form. such as;

```
.
.
.
//some process
if(model.UserName == "foo")
{
//some process
}
if(model.City != "Istanbul")
{
   //Alert user; Are you sure you want to continue bla bla bla...
  //Then user click if 'yes' some process else some process
}
```

I thought, keep object in session and show javascript confirm message. if user click 'yes' or no i create hidden input match viewModel's property and set input value user's choise. then submit form automatcally.
but i thought again, it's way not good. What is the bestpractice for?

Comment: I'd make the check using AJAX, and show a javascript dialog using jQuery UI or some such before submitting the form.

Comment: For the love of UX, stay away from modal popup dialogs!

Comment: I can't use ajax or JQuery UI because my project run on windows mobile ce or 5.0. I can just use only simple javascript statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What u have thought about javascript is quite right. JS is the best practise for this type of scenario. It will add some attraction to ur page. Though u can do this from C# itself by putting a 'visible' property true/false when a event would be triggered.